# I have this question and this answer but they make no sense....?

Tags: geometry

I have this question...

> In $\mathbb{R}^n$, show that 
>   $$\|u+v\| \leqslant\|u\|+\|v\|.$$
>   Hint: The result of the previous exercise may help.

and this answer...

[image]

But I can't see how they go from the circled line to the last line?

and why are the absolute values in line 3 less than or equal to the original values in line 2?

Thanks!

Comment: If $\,a^2 \le b^2\,$ and $\,a,b \ge 0\,$ then $\,a \le b\,$. This is because $\,a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b) \,$ and, with $\,a+b \ge 0\,$, it follows that $\,a^2-b^2\,$ and $\,a-b\,$ have the same sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:
$$u\cdot v=|u|\cdot |v|\cdot \cos \alpha \Rightarrow u\cdot v\le |u|\cdot |v|.$$
Second: take square root:
$$(|u+v|)^2\le (|u|+|v|)^2 \Rightarrow |u+v|\le |u|+|v|.$$

Answer (score 3):

The main calculation shows $\Vert u+v\Vert^2\leq (\Vert u\Vert+\Vert v\Vert)^2$. We can take square roots since the norms are nonnegative, and we get $\Vert u+v\Vert\leq \Vert u\Vert+\Vert v\Vert$.

Note, when $a,b\geq 0$ we have $a^2\leq b^2\implies a\leq b$, so taking square roots in this instance preserves the inequality.

**Answer to your additional question:** This really comes from the fact that $u\cdot v\leq \Vert u\Vert\Vert v\Vert$. This fact is likely (I assume) the "previous exercise" indicated in your hint.

Answer (score 1):

You have proven that $\| u+v\|^2 \le (\|u\|+\|v\|)^2$, to get the result, we take square root.

Comment: Right! I don't know how I didn't see that! now my second question is why are the absolute values less than or equal to the original values?

Comment: you mean absolute value is at least greater or equal to the original values right?